# Athena query in Sage maker notebook. How to get the location of output file for reusability?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-sagemaker

My query worked:

```
from pyathena import connect
import pandas as pd
conn = connect(s3_staging_dir='s3://alphabucket/query-results/myfolder/',region_name='us-east-1')

df = pd.read_sql("select * from mydbname.mytablename limit 8;", conn)
```

How ever.. next time when I run the notebook, I would like to avoid running the query again.

I am looking for API that would return me the result file.

eg:

```
df = pd.read_sql("select * from mydbname.mytablename limit 8;", conn)
file = conn.last_query_output_location() # Hypothetical function Doesnt Work
print(file) # --> s3://alphabucket/query-results/myfolder/2021/07/23/dfjj00772hh.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the dataframe of the query result by uploading the dataframe as a csv file to your S3 bucket. Then recreate a dataframe from the csv in the S3 bucket.

[ref: boto3 upload_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file)

```
# after dataframe created with Athena query.

import boto3

# Save on EC2 storage
file_name = "mydata.csv" 
df.to_csv(file_name)

# Upload to S3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, file_key)
```

Re-create dataframe by reading from S3

```
s3uri = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, file_key)
df = pd.read_csv(s3uri)
```

Comment: Its a work around. The Querry results is already there in S3. Instead of re using  the S3 location, do we need to copy to local and copy back to S3 ?

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding. Above are saving `df` itself and re-using them. And uploading local of sagemaker should be required to uploading to S3 (as I read a troubleshoot somewhere).